# convert single wire connectors to 9 wire

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I want to install a ceiling fan light into an existing ceiling fan? The new light has 2 single wire connectors wires to plug in to the ceiling fan which has a 9 wire plug in connector. how to convert ?

Comment: please take the tour so you can learn how to best participate.    Also, questions like this are impossible to answer without more details, such as model numbers, pictures, etc .

Comment: Typically fans are designed to only accept specifically matched light kits. This is partly for proprietary reasons (aka "vendor lock-in") but also serves a real purpose in making sure that an attached light is suitable (weight, balance, power) for use with a particular fan. **Post the model numbers of the fan & light** and we might be able to help.

Comment: Actually another potentially **huge** complication. There are fans now designed for use with LED lights. Such lights *may* be a low voltage (i.e., converted and controlled by the fan electronics rather than simply a switched pass-through 120V) or vice versa - mix and match such things and you could (a) simply have things not work or (b) have serious safety problems (e.g., "exploding light fixtures").

Comment: Is the fan light actually made and UL-listed specifically to fit in that particular ceiling fan? Does it have instructions?

Comment: Can you post make/model numbers and/or instructions for the fan and light kit?